# How to create offline ionic app ?

Tags: ionic-framework, cross-platform, pouchdb, offlineapps

I have an app in ionic, I want to make it offline. What procedure should I follow..? if I have to start from beginning please explain it step by step.Simply i want to create a offline app using ionic, explain each and every step. I tried lot's of thing.
Please Thank you.

Comment: *I tried lot's of thing* ? For example? Please state it **step by step**.

Comment: Means i followed links like https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronizing-offline-app-data-with-pouchdb/

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat i followed many link but not get any proper idea

Comment: What is the main purpose of your application? I mean what is that specific feature you want to build?

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat all functionality of my app should be work offline , Example:- Signup, login, it should be upload a text file.